# Adobe Cq Dialog Box Highliter issue

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr, crx

I have a component called in my template like this:

```
<cq:include path="par4" resourceType="/apps/mobile/properties/components/content/homepage_carousel-mobile" />
```

The Dialog highliter does not appears unless I change the par from par4 to some thing else ?

The problem is whenever I add a new component to the template the highliter stops working on some of previously added components. And then I have to change pars in the components all the way along to fix this.

Is there any way the highliter could automatically come without changing the pars of components?

Sorry if I am not clear in explaining my problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the bounding box (green/orange) doesn't show when you hover over the component? Have you turned off decoration on any components? This could have a cascading effect & affect ones further down the page if not implemented correctly.

Comment: u are absolutely correct i am talking about the bounding box(green/orange). I have not palyed with the decoration you are talking about can u plz guide where can i find this decoration .

Comment: [See here for more about Component decoration][1] and [here for properties such as `cq:htmlTag`, `cq:noDecoration` and `cq:cellName`][2] that could all have an affect. I'd say try two things — add your components to the Geometrixx default site & see if the same still happens. Secondly, remove your JavaScript from the page & see if that's causing a conflict — if you have JS editing class names, it could affect the page in edit-mode.


  [1]: http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/ComponentDiv.html
  [2]: https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it instead of only par i gave it like this and things started working i started getting the highliter for each component

```
<cq:include path="par4/homepage_carousel-mobile" resourceType="/apps/mobile/properties/components/content/homepage_carousel-mobile" />
```